# Adding information to dynamic listboxs

Tags: vba, excel

In my userform I have a question that reads:

```
Number of Students?
```

And whatever number the user inputs they will receive a dynamic textbox & listbox for each number (so if user enters 2 they will receive a dynamic textbox & listbox  + another dynamic textbox & listbox). What I then want to do is insert the number that is input into the dynamic textbox into its corressponding listbox but I can't get it to work. Below shows the code that I have so far:

```
Option Explicit

Dim TextBox() As New Class3
Dim ListBox() As New Class3

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim i As Integer
Dim buttonStartPosition As Integer
Dim BtxtStartPosition As Integer
Dim listStartPosition As Integer
Dim BlabelStartPosition As Integer
Dim newPosition As Integer
Dim cButton As CommandButton
Dim cText As Control
Dim cList As Control

buttonStartPosition = 30
BtxtStartPosition = 270
listStartPosition = 290

If TextBox1 <> vbNullString Then
    For i = 1 To TextBox1.Value
    newPosition = 200

    Set cText = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
        With cText
            .Name = "breakerText" & (i)
            .Left = 174
            .Top = BtxtStartPosition
            .Width = 72
            .Height = 15.75
    End With

    ReDim Preserve TextBox(1 To i)
    Set TextBox(i).TextGroup = cText
    BtxtStartPosition = BtxtStartPosition + newPosition

    Set cList = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ListBox.1")
        With cList
            .Name = "listbox_" & (i)
            .Left = 150
            .Top = listStartPosition
            .Width = 300
            .Height = 140
        End With

    ReDim Preserve ListBox(1 To i)
    Set ListBox(i).ListGroup = cList
    listStartPosition = listStartPosition + newPosition
```

Then I have the class that does the functions for the dynamic controls:

```
Public WithEvents ListGroup As MSForms.ListBox
Public WithEvents TextGroup As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub TextGroup_Change()
If TextGroup.Name = "breakerText1" Then
 'Insert into listbox1

ElseIf TextGroup.Name = "breakerText2" Then
'Insert into listbox2

End If

End Sub
```

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction here, I just need the dynamic textbox value populated into its corresponding textbox. Below shows and image of the userform to give a better understanding of the matter.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

**Userform code:**

```
Option Explicit

Dim TextListBox() As New Class3

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim i As Integer
Dim buttonStartPosition As Integer
Dim BtxtStartPosition As Integer
Dim listStartPosition As Integer
Dim BlabelStartPosition As Integer
Dim newPosition As Integer
Dim cButton As CommandButton
Dim cText As Control
Dim cList As Control

buttonStartPosition = 30
BtxtStartPosition = 270
listStartPosition = 290

If TextBox1 <> vbNullString Then
    ReDim TextListBox(1 To TextBox1.Value)
    For i = 1 To TextBox1.Value
    newPosition = 200

    Set cText = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
        With cText
            .Name = "breakerText" & (i)
            .Left = 174
            .Top = BtxtStartPosition
            .Width = 72
            .Height = 15.75
    End With

    Set TextListBox(i).TextGroup = cText
    BtxtStartPosition = BtxtStartPosition + newPosition

    Set cList = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ListBox.1")
        With cList
            .Name = "listbox_" & (i)
            .Left = 150
            .Top = listStartPosition
            .Width = 300
            .Height = 140
        End With

    Set TextListBox(i).ListGroup = cList
    listStartPosition = listStartPosition + newPosition
    Next i
End If
End Sub
```

**Class3 code**:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents ListGroup As MSForms.ListBox
Public WithEvents TextGroup As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub TextGroup_Change()
    ListGroup.AddItem TextGroup.Text
End Sub
```

However, because you use the change event, you will add an item to the list for each keystroke in the textbox. Since you can't use the usual Exit or Before/After_Update events with a WithEvents control, I'd suggest you use a command button.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! Takes a whiel to get used to dynamic controls lol